# Using ng-repeat on a position of $scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, web, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a array like:

```
$scope.items = [];
$scope.items[0] = {val1: 1, val2: 2}
```

I'm trying to use an ng-repeat like:

```
<div ng-repeat = "item in items[0]"> {{item.val1}} </div>
```

which it is the right way to use this? Thanks :D !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`items[0]` is not an array but object so you need to use `(key, value) in expression` notation (see [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)) to iterate over object properties:

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in items[0]">{{key}} {{value}}</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, what is exactly key and value?. In my scope item y have another scope, thats the reason of mi question :D

Comment: Finally this was my solution, i do something like: <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in items[0]">{{value.value2}}</div>

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what are you trying to achieve. See, there are two things to iterate here (it can make sense to iterate either, depending on your needs):

- the elements of the array
- the properties of the object *(the object being any array element)*.

To iterate the **elements of the array**, use:

```
<div ng-repeat = "item in items"> {{item.val1}} </div>
```

in this case, `item` will be the current element of the array, and the statement above will print the `val1` property of every element in the array.

To iterate the **properties of the object**, use:

```
<div ng-repeat = "item in items[0]"> {{item}} </div>
```

This will print every property of the first element of the array.
`items[0]` is an object, and you're iterating through its properties here (so `item` inside the ng-repeat will reference properties). As such, it doesn't make sense to write `item.val1`, because `item` will be `1` (in your example), not an object, but a primitive.

Of course, you can also iterate **every property of every array element, by combining the two**:

```
<div ng-repeat = "item in items">
    <div ng-repeat = "prop in item">{{prop}} </div>
</div>
```

This will print every property of every item in the array.

Deciding which one to use depends on your use-case.